Возможно ли обратиться к элементу коллекции по индексу внутри LINQ-запроса?
Прохожу тему LINQ в своем обучении. Дано задание выполнить несколько простых операций со строками, написав всего один LINQ-запрос.
Вопрос следующий. В рамках данной задачи необходимо пропустить первую строку (заголовок), затем каждую из строк разделить на три части, выполнить парсинг двух частей из них (третья должна остаться строкой), а затем создать и вернуть объект с полями, которым присвоены результирующие значения. Но как это можно сделать не имея возможность обратиться к каждой из трех частей разделенной строки по индексу, я не понимаю.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, знатоки LINQ, как обычно решаются подобные задачи, и как можно написать решение в данном случае?
Пример входящей строки:
SlideId;SlideType;UnitTitle
0;theory;Первое знакомство с C#
1;quiz;Первое знакомство с C#
2;theory;Первое знакомство с C#
3;exercise;Первое знакомство с C#

Код метода:
public static IDictionary<int, SlideRecord> ParseSlideRecords(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    return ...
}


Вот прям как написано, так и решается. Пропустить - Skip. Разделить - string.Split. Парсинг - int.Parse. Создать объект - new SlideRecord.

Спасибо за ответ! Но ведь выполняя Split у нас должны получаться три отдельных объекта, каждый из которых нужно парсить по-разному. Плюс нужно как-то заложить условие пропуска (перехода к следующей строке) при некорректной строке, либо выброс исключения. Это тоже возможно сделать?

Я так понимаю, смущает "лямбда выражения", которая обычно идет как название => что-то делаем с названием (x=> x.Split()), и в которой вы должны еще что-то сделать, но не можете... Правильно понял вопрос? Если да, то лямбда, это не просто 1 значение, а по сути, метод, который выполняется в данный момент. Условно, если x это string, а на выход должен идти массив разбитый, то вы можете сделать метод string[] Some(string text) {  return text.Split()  }  и дальше использовать как .Select(Some) или .Select(x=>Some(x)) и т.д.

Также вы можете раскрыть лямбду и прописать действия там (x=> { var data = x.Split(); return data;  }). Вот собственно и делайте метод, или прям в лямбде, пишите логику разбития, парсинга, и возвращайте потом нужный вид данных.

Спасибо за ответ! Лямбды не смущают, что это и как пользоваться я знаю. Смущает то, что с разными частями строки нужно сделать разные действия (грубо - первая часть порядковый номер, вторая дата, третья название), а значит должна быть какая-то логика сравнения ожидаемого и фактического значения и пропуск строки, если данные некорректные.
Раскрыть лямбду превратив в почти обычный метод - это скорее всего слишком уж прямолинейное решение, авторы курса не могли такое сделать. Скорее всего, всё просто и изящно можно сделать, это я у себя в голове всё переусложняю.

Вам так или иначе надо данные сначала парсить. Если речь про чистый LINQ, то должно быть что-то по типу lines.Select(x => { var parts = x.Split(';'); return new { Id = int.Parse(parts[0]), Record = new SlideRecord(...) }; }).ToDictionary(key => key.Id, value => value.Record); (не знаю что такое SlideRecord, сами думаю разберетесь), но в целом, по другому тут не получиться. Можете "раскрытие" заменить на двойной .Select(), где сначала будет Split, а потом формирование нужных данных с нужными конвертациями.

Нельзя ли чуть подробнее про двойной Select? Сам в эту же сторону думаю, но не могу понять как их "сдружить" всех вместе. По логике должно быть так: Мы применяем Select к сплитованной строке, парсим первый элемент. До третьего можно добраться с помощью Last. Но не могу понять как добраться до второго...

.Select(x=>x.Split(';')) - получите коллекцию из string[] с разбитой каждой строкой. Далее вам надо формировать из этого нужный вид, опять .Select(x=> new { Id = int.Parse(x[0]), Record = new SlideRecord(...) }) (тут x это string[]), ну и дальше как показал выше.

Спасибо, получилось! Можно еще раскрытие заменить созданием кортежа - на лекции это объясняли, только сейчас вспомнил))

Запрос можно покороче и попроще сделать:
// .NET Framework 4.8
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
enum SlideType { theory, quiz, exercise }
class SlideRecord {
    public SlideType SlideType;
    public string UnitTitle;
    public SlideRecord(string[] slide)
        { Enum.TryParse<SlideType>(slide[1], out SlideType); UnitTitle = slide[2]; }
    public override string ToString() { return "#" + SlideType + " " + UnitTitle; }
}
static class Program {
    public static IDictionary<int, SlideRecord> ParseSlideRecords(IEnumerable<string> lines) {
        int itp; SlideType etp;
        return lines.Skip(1).Select(s => s.Split(';'))
            .Where(w => int.TryParse(w[0], out itp) // проверка первого элемента
                && Enum.TryParse<SlideType>(w[1], out etp)) // проверка второго элемента
            .ToDictionary(t => int.Parse(t[0]), t => new SlideRecord(t)); // используем удобный конструктор
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var input = new string[] { "SlideId;SlideType;UnitTitle",
            "0;theory;Первое знакомство с C#",
            "1;quiz;Первое знакомство с C#",
            "2в1;theory;Первое знакомство с C#",
            "3;exercise;Первое знакомство с C#" };
        foreach (var kvp in ParseSlideRecords(input))
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}

==>

0: #theory Первое знакомство с C#
1: #quiz Первое знакомство с C#
3: #exercise Первое знакомство с C#

P. S. Добавил .Where(w => int.TryParse(w[0], out itp)) для отбора корректных значений. В данном случае оно не будет пропускать и первую строку, и .Skip(1) можно убрать. Но для общего применения .Skip(1) нужно оставить.

Да, действительно. Можно провести парсинг при создании словаря. Я пока плохо знаю даже основные LINQ-методы, не говоря уже об их перегрузках, и переусложняю логику. А как бы еще заложить логику пропуска некорректной строки, либо выброс исключения? Такое возможно?

Можно, см. дополнение в ответе.

"основные LINQ-методы" в https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-8.0

Благодарю за помощь!

Пропустить можно только с помощью метода отбора Where, никакие другие методы "пропусков" не позволяют. Ну, и исключение прекратит выполнение всего, так что тоже не вариант.

А как же Skip? Применял его, благополучно скипает первый элемент и работает дальше.
Не совсем понял, что значит "исключение прекратит выполнение всего"...

Skip это да, я имел ввиду методы типа Select или ToDictionary. Исключение вызовет прекращение выполнения всего запроса, но не пропуск какой-то итерации.

А зачем это всё, если есть библиотека CsvHelper?

@aepot Потому что вопрос про Linq, а не про разбор csv.

Но разве было бы лишним подсказать автору, как легче разбирать CSV файлы?

@aepot Покажите, раз вы в теме. Я не думал в этом направлении.

@aepot, совсем не лишним, просто сейчас прохожу тему LINQ, а решаемая задача - всего лишь способ покопаться в теме и получше ее узнать.

@JamesBond https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ вот документация. Просто поставьте библиотеку CsvHelper из NuGet и пробуйте, примеров полинтернета. Она вам и заголовок распарсит и экземпляры класса заполнит.

@aepot вспомнил про Log4j. Почему бы не воспользоваться готовой библиотекой? :-)

@aepot благодарю, учту на будущее!

int.TryParse(w[0], out _)

Аналогично Enum.TryParse<SlideType>(w[1], out _). Не нужно значение, замените его на "заглушку" (нижнее подчеркивание), а не делайте лишнюю переменную, которая будет кушать память.

Запускал на .NET 8. В данном решении валидации на значения нет, т. к. по задаче это не требуется. На вход используется именно строка, как написано по задаче, а не строковый массив. Вывод в консоль через тип record.
class Program
{
    public enum SlideType {
        Theory,
        Quiz,
        Exercise,
    }

    public record SlideRecord
    {
        public SlideType SlideType { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public static IDictionary<int, SlideRecord> ParseSlideRecords(IEnumerable<string> lines)
    {
        const int id = 0;
        const int slideType = 1;
        const int message = 2;
        const string separator = ";";

        return lines.Skip(1)
            .Select(line => line.Split(separator))
            .ToDictionary(line => int.Parse(line[id]), line => new SlideRecord
            {
                SlideType = Enum.Parse<SlideType>(line[slideType], true),
                Message = line[message],
            });
    }
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Входящая строка
        var input = """
                    SlideId;SlideType;UnitTitle
                    0;theory;Первое знакомство с C#
                    1;quiz;Первое знакомство с C#
                    2;theory;Первое знакомство с C#
                    3;exercise;Первое знакомство с C#
                    """;

        // Разбиваем на массив, который подойдёт для метода
        var lines = input.Split(Environment.NewLine);
        // Вызываем метод, получаем результат
        var slides = ParseSlideRecords(lines);
        // Выводим на консоль
        foreach(var slide in slides)
            Console.WriteLine($"{slide.Key}: {slide.Value}");
    }
}

